# ExceptionHandler for a pre-controller Filter (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, exception

I have a question about the exceptions on the Spring security level.

I user the SM_USER header for authorization and for the validation the request goes through the DelegateRequestMatchingFilter (it helps to understand whether the SM_USER is needed).

The problem is that if there is no SM_USER-header at all the line `super.doFilter(...)` throws a `PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException` which cannot be processed with the standard ExceptionResolver for controllers and that's why looks strange and differs from all the other exception thrown by the application.

I tried to write an own method marked with `@ExceptionResolver` annotation for the filter, but it is ignored.

How can I insert an ExceptionsResolver for this Filter?

**DelegateRequestMatchingFilter snippet**

```
public class DelegateRequestMatchingFilter extends RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter {

private RequestMatcher ignoredRequests;
public DelegateRequestMatchingFilter(RequestMatcher matcher) {
    super();
    super.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    this.ignoredRequests = matcher;
}   

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

     HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;      
     if(ignoredRequests.matches(httpReq)) {
         chain.doFilter(req,resp);
     } else {
         super.doFilter(req,resp,chain);//<-- throws exception
     }       
}   
}
```

Fragment from **ExceptionResolver** which does not solve the problem because it works only for controllers

```
 @ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{


@Override
protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse responce, Object handler, Exception exception) {

    ModelAndView toReturn = new ModelAndView();
    toReturn.setView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
    toReturn.addObject("message", exception.getMessage());
    toReturn.addObject("exceptionClass", exception.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    return toReturn;
}

@ExceptionHandler(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException.class)       
public ResponseEntity<Result> handleBindException(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException e) {

    Result result = new Result("the identification header is missing");
    result.setException(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException.class);
    ResponseEntity<Result> response = new ResponseEntity<Result>(result, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    return response;
}
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;  
private PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedProvider;



@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    Map<String, List<GrantedAuthority>> rolesAuthorities = getRolesWithAutorities();

    userDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService(...);
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = 
            new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(userDetailsService);
    preAuthenticatedProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedProvider);
}   

@Bean
public SmUserFailureHandler smUserFailureHandler(){
    return new SmUserFailureHandler();
}

@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    AccessDeniedHandlerImpl handler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
    handler.setErrorPage("/errorPage/");        
    return handler;     
}

public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter() throws Exception
{

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new DelegateRequestMatchingFilter(
            new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/uriToSkip/")));

    siteMinderFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());   
    return siteMinderFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  

 //...   
 http.addFilter(siteMinderFilter());
 ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http.authorizeRequests();
  //adding methods... 
  http = registry.and();

  http.csrf().disable();
  http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
  http
  .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);    
}
}
```

If I change my code according to the answer, I get this exception even SM_USEr header is present and is correct

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:133)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: may be filter are on top of spring layer, that's why its not working

Comment: @VinitSolanki, yes maybe. And the question is how  I can make it work.

Answer (score 3):

At first, you should add your filter after `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, this filter will handle the `AccessDeniedException` and `AuthenticationException` when it catches them.

```
http.addFilterAfter(siteMinderFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
```

and next you need inject a `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to handle `AuthenticationException`, there are some already exist `AuthenticationEntryPoint` you can use it, like `HttpStatusEntryPoint`, `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`, ...;

If you want to return a JSON response you need to implement your own `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, for example:

```
public class ExampleAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error(authException.getMessage(), authException);
        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMsg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            responseMsg.put("message", authException.getMessage());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                writer.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(responseMsg));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's better to return http statue code `401` instead of `403`, `403` is used for `AccessDeniedException`;

and then inject your own `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to `ExceptionTranslationFilter`;

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(myEntryPoint());

@Bean
AuthenticationEntryPoint myEntryPoint() {
    return new ExampleAuthenticationEntryPoint();
}

/*
Or just return 401
AuthenticationEntryPoint myEntryPoint() {
    return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
} 
*/
```

BTW:

If you set `continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication` to `true` in `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`, the exception will not throw in super filter, and its default value is `true`, maybe you need to set it to false, or you will need to inject a `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in `DelegateRequestMatchingFilter` to handle the exception when do authentication.

** UPDATE **

```
else if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) || authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
                logger.debug(
                        "Access is denied (user is " + (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) ? "anonymous" : "not fully authenticated") + "); redirecting to authentication entry point",
                        exception);

                sendStartAuthentication(
                        request,
                        response,
                        chain,
                        new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                                "Full authentication is required to access this resource"));
            }
            else {
                logger.debug(
                        "Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler",
                        exception);

                accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,
                        (AccessDeniedException) exception);
            }
        }
```

As you can read from the code, now it's `AccessDeniedException`, I think you can disable the Anonymous user or you need to check why you get `AccessDeniedException`.

`http.anonymous().disable();`

**UPDATE 2**

```
Authentication currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!checkForPrincipalChanges) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!principalChanged(request, currentUser)) {
        return false;
    }
```

default value of `checkForPrincipalChanges` is `false`, so now if you enable the `anon` filter, this will return false and skip do authentication in `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`, so just try do disable `anon` filter. and you need to learn spring security code and research it by debugging.

Comment: no. it does not work. he throws an exception for exery request.

Comment: could you post more infomation？ exception stack？

Comment: yes. if I make a request even with the correct SM_USER it throws an exception: InsufficientAuthenticationException. I will add the text to the questuin body

Comment: so i think that the thing is: the spring security throws this exception in any case and it is catched by my entryPoint.

Comment: I think you did not understand me: I catch InsufficientAuthenticationException (which is a child of AccessDeniedException) with my entraPoint with every request: even in the case of correct SM_USEr. It does not start calling CustomUserDetailsService to check wether the user really exist - just thorws an exception.
If I shut the entryPoint and the line with ExceptionTranslationFilter off, I do not receive any exceptions

Comment: Please try to disable `anon` and see my update. BTW: the default value of `principalRequestHeader` is `SM_USER` in source code.