# custom exception is not passing through Advice control in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I'm trying to customize a thrown exception, but it's not in the advice control.

The TokenExpiredException exception
should be handled in controller advice, but returns a common, unhandled error.

JWTValidarFilter:

```
public class JWTValidarFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter{

private static final String HEADER_ATRIBUTO = "Authorization";

private static final String ATRIBUTO_PREFIXO = "Bearer ";

public JWTValidarFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    String atributo = request.getHeader(HEADER_ATRIBUTO);
            
    if(atributo == null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    
    if(!atributo.startsWith(ATRIBUTO_PREFIXO)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    
    String token = atributo.replace(ATRIBUTO_PREFIXO, "");
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    
    
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(String token) {
    
    
    try {
        String usuario = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(JWTAutenticarFilter.TOKEN_SENHA))
                .build()
                .verify(token)
                .getSubject();
        if(usuario == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario, null, new ArrayList<>());

    } catch (TokenExpiredException e) {
        throw new TokenExpiredException("Token expirado!");
    }
    
}
```

}

CustomizeResponseEntityExceptionHandler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizeResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleAllExcepetions(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = 
                new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidJwtAuthenticationException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> invalidJwtAuthenticationException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = 
                new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), 
                        ex.getMessage(), 
                        request.getDescription(false));
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(TokenExpiredException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> TokenExpiredException(TokenExpiredException ex, WebRequest request){
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = 
                new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), 
                        ex.getMessage(), 
                        request.getDescription(true));
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(HttpClientErrorException ex) throws HttpClientErrorException {
        System.out.println("*******Exception Occured: *************" + ex);
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .body(" -----DD------ Exception: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

2021-09-28 10:13:38.729 ERROR 25385 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.TokenExpiredException: Token expirado!

Comment: Have you tried removing `@RestController` from `CustomizeResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. It is not needed and might be causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything...

Comment: Then my guess is that the issue is that `@ControllerAdvice`only applies to `@Controller` classes and `@ExceptionHandler` only handles exceptions thrown by the Controllers. Your exception is thrown by a custom `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: got it, so how would I handle this exception?

Comment: Keep in mind this is just I guess. I will try to find another way to do it.

Comment: In the past, I have had to use a backstop filter to catch exceptions thrown in other filters: `try {  doFilterChain(req, rsp, chain); } catch ( Throwable ex ) {  logger.error("Uncaught!", ex); sendErrorResponse(rsp); }`.   The backstop filter must have the highest precedence (1st in the chain, starts 1st, finishes last).

Answer (score 1):

Try building a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` as follows:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler 
  implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
 
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
       AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Throwable cause = exception.getCause();
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = null;

        if (cause instanceOf InvalidJwtAuthenticationException) {
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
          exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), 
                cause.getMessage(), 
                request.getDescription(false));
        } else if (cause instanceOf TokenExpiredException) {
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
          exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), 
                ex.getMessage(), 
                request.getDescription(true));
        } else {
          // additional logic here
        }

        response.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(exceptionResponse));
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it in a `@Configuration` class:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
```

Comment: This is not helpfull, no recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch authentication exceptions using controller advice (at least not as simple :-). Authentication exceptions happen before the whole Spring exception handler intialized. Here ist similar discussion how to workaround related issues:

[Spring MVC (or Spring Boot). Custom JSON response for security related exceptions like 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679897/spring-mvc-or-spring-boot-custom-json-response-for-security-related-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication Exception can not be handled using such **@ExceptionHandler**, because it just happens before the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet were entered and all the MVC handlers were initialized. So you need to create a Class that inherit interface **AuthenticationEntryPoint**, override the **commence()** method and handle the exception there as you need. Here is the example:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOGGER.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        UnauthorizedException exception = new UnauthorizedException("Please provide auth token");
        String responseMsg = mapper.writeValueAsString(exception);
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(responseMsg);
    }
}
```

Add add below lines to your Spring Security Config that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
```

and it becomes like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecutiryConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecutiryConfig(UserRepository userRepository,
                          CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService,
                          JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler,
                          JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter)
    {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler) // this line
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```